# Reading math equations in from file

Tags: c++

I'm making a program where the users get a menu like this

```
Multiplication 1
Division 2
Subtraction 3
Addition 4
Review 5
```

where they can choose an option and put in the number range they want to work with and how many problems they want to do and it generates math problems for them.

That part works and I have it so when they get one wrong it puts the problem into a file `math.txt` using `fout` and that works.

What I'm trying to do now is when they choose to review it reads in the file and gives them those problems.

The file is in the format of (for example)

```
1 + 1 = 
2 * 2 =
```

I'm just not sure how to read in the numbers and identify what operation it is (multiplication, addition etc.)

I've tried just getting it to read in a number with

```
std::ifstream fin("math.txt");
int x;
fin>>x;
```

But that returns `0` everytime.

So to summarize, my question is-- How can I read in a file and pull the equation (ex. 4 + 4 = \n 3 / 3 = ) so that the user can solve it?

Comment: Close voters: why _Too Broad_? OP is trying to read a single line from a file, what's broad about that?

Comment: Was the file opened correctly? You should check than before reading from it. (*although I'm not sure if that's the problem here*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that you haven't flushed the previous write operation. You can either do this explicitly with `flush()` or `close()` your `fout` instance. Example:

```
std::ofstream fou("math.txt");
fou << "1 + 1 =";
// Need this: fou.close();

std::ifstream fin("math.txt");
int x;
fin >> x;
std::cout << x;
```

I was able to reproduce your problem when `fou.close()` was missing.